# git status command - New files not listed

Tags: git, visual-studio

Context: Windows - After running a localization script, the Visual Studio "Git Changes" window correctly shows the new files (A) and modified files (M). However when i use 'git status' the new items are not listed.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status shows they should be listed with 'A'.

> > So what do i need to do get the same list from the git command line as I get visibly from Visual Studio?

Most of the new files extensions will get added to the .gitignore once i vet them.
Thanks

Comment: Unless this localization script itself runs `git add`, new files should *not* show up as status `A`, but rather as status `??` (in short mode) or *untracked* (in regular status output).

Comment: Thanks but dont we have a catch 22, without a file list we can't add specific files? 
The ?? items included in the list with --short are only new directories, not new files. NB: My git knowledge is basic. I see the help has 'git add . - Stage all files" but it is not clear if this everything or just the new files?

Comment: Ah: the `untracked files` output from Git tries (often successfully as in this case) to *shorten the output* by listing the directory name—i.e., just one thing—instead of every-file-in-the-directory (many lines of output). You can tell Git "don't shorten the output" with `-uall`, but that just makes the output long. The theory here is that you can either add the entire directory (`git add .` or `git add path/to/dir` or whatever), or—if you don't want to do that—you have the *entire command line full of commands* with which to *look inside* the directory.

Comment: As for `git add .` or `git add --all`: try running `git ls-files --stage` some time (but be aware that this can produce a LOT of output) to see what's in the staging area. The surprise for Git newbies is that *every file is always staged*, except for those files that are untracked.

Comment: The trick here is that the copy in the staging area is a *separate copy*, sitting "in between" the *committed* copy (which you cannot change) and the working tree copy (which is a plain file, but is not in Git at all). The index's copy is the copy that will go into the *next* commit. Like any committed file, it's already de-duplicated against all other committed files—so if it's the same as the existing committed file (or even any earlier file) it takes no space.

Comment: Running `git add .` or `git add path/to/dir` tells Git to find and add *all* files in the named directory, with the exception of any files that are (a) currently untracked *and* (b) listed in a `.gitignore` or similar. Both conditions must hold for Git to *not* add the file. "Adding" a file consists of compressing it, de-duplicating it, and putting that compressed and de-duplicated copy into the index/staging-area. If that copy matches the current committed copy, it takes no space, so it's fine to re-add files you haven't modified (it's just a slight waste of time, is all).

Comment: VS presumably lists every file because *you're trapped in VS*, and there's no huge universe of shell commands that let you program anything you like: you can only do those things that VS has pre-programmed into it. In any case, if you want `git status` to list every individual file every time—usually this is a big waste of your eyeballs—you can just run `git status -uall`.

Comment: the "git status -uall" is fine, i can parse the output. In my case the changed files are preceeeded by "  modified: " while the untracked have no prefix. 
Thanks for the additional info
If you add this as an Answer i can tick it as the answer.

Comment: The thing is, if you're going to *parse* the output, don't use `git status` like this: use `git status --porcelain` or `git ls-files --other` or similar. These outputs are *designed* to be machine-parsed.